# Let $X$ be any topological soace which satisfies the first axiom of countability. If every compact subset of $X$ is closed, then $X$ is Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

Let $X$ be any topological soace which satisfies the first axiom of countability. If every compact subset of $X$ is closed, then $X$ is Hausdorff.

> proof: Suppose that every compact subset of $X$ is closed. Since $X$ satisfies the first axiom of countability, to establish that $X$ is hausdorff it is sufficient to show that no sequence in $X$ converges to nore than one point. Let $\{s_n\}$ be a sequence in $X$ which converges to the points $p$ and $q$. We show that $p = q$. We dividee the proof into three cases.
>
> (a): $\{ s_n\} $ is frequently in the set $\{p\}$. Then $\{p\}$ has a subsequence $\{ t_n \}$ s.t $t_n = p$ for all $n $. Since $\{ p \}$ is finite it is compact and hence by hypothesis closed. Since $\{ s_n \}$ converges to $q$. $\{ t_n \}$ converges to $q$. WE conclude $ q \in \{ p \}$, and so $p=q$.
>
> (b);$\{ s_n\} $ is frequently in the set $\{q\}$.
>
> (c): $\{ s_n\} $ is neither frequently in the set $\{p\}$ nor  frequently in the set $\{q\}$. Then there existe a positive integer $m$  s.t for $n‎\geq‎‎‎‎m$, $\{ s_n\}  \not\in p,q$ .Let $\{ t_n\} $ be the subsequence of $\{ s_n\} $ definde by $ t_n = ‎s‎_{m +n}$ for all $n$. Then $\{t_n\} $converges to $p$ and $q$. Let $T$ be the range of $\{t_n\}$ . Then  by definition of $\{t_n\}$, $p \not\in T , q \not\in T$. concider  the set $ W = T \cup \{p\}$  the to. so $W$ is compact . then  by hypothesis $W$ is closed. Since $\{t_n\}$ is a sequence in the set closed set $W$ converges to $q$ We conclude that $q \in W$. since $q \not\in T, q = p$.

In part (a):

what does it mean "**$\{ s_n\} $ is frequently in the set $\{p\}$. Then $\{p\}$ has a subsequence $\{ t_n \}$ s.t $t_n = p$ for all $n $"** ?

In part (c):

what does it mean **" $\{ s_n\} $ is neither frequently in the set $\{p\}$ nor  frequently in the set $\{q\}$. Then there existe a positive integer $m$  s.t for $n‎\geq‎‎‎‎m$, $\{ s_n\}  \not\in p,q$"?
 and " $T$ be the range of $\{t_n\}$ " ?**

Answer (score 1):

If $\sigma=\langle s_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ is a sequence in a set $X$, and $A\subseteq X$, we say that $\sigma$ is *frequently in* $A$ if $\{n\in\omega:x_n\in A\}$ is infinite. This can also be expressed by saying that for each $n\in\omega$ there is a $k>n$ such that $x_k\in A$. If $\{n\in\omega:x_n\in A\}=\{n_k:k\in\omega\}$, where $n_{k+1}>n_k$ for each $k\in\omega$, then $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\omega\rangle$ is clearly a subsequence of $\sigma$ whose terms are all in $A$; if $A=\{p\}$, this means that $x_{n_k}=p$ for each $k\in\omega$.

If $\sigma$ is **not** frequently in $A$, then $\{n\in\omega:x_n\in A\}$ is finite, and there is an $m_A\in\omega$ such that $x_n\notin A$ whenever $n\ge m_A$. If $B$ is another subset of $X$, and $\sigma$ is not frequently in $B$, then similarly there is an $m_B\in\omega$ such that $x_n\notin B$ whenever $n\ge m_B$. Let $m=\max\{m_A,m_B\}$; then $x_n\notin A\cup B$ whenever $n\ge m$. If $A=\{p\}$ and $B=\{q\}$, this means that $p\ne x_n\ne q\}$ whenever $n\ge m$.

Comment: Thanks for answer.Here,what does it mean "" $T$  be the range of $\{t_ n \}$ "?

Comment: @fatemeh: You’re welcome. A sequence $\langle t_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ is a function whose domain is $\omega$ and whose range is $\{t_n:n\in\omega\}$. The notation $\{t_n\}$ for sequences is sloppy and misleading, because it obscures the fact that the sequence $\langle t_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ is not the same thing as the set $\{t_n:n\in\omega\}$, which is the range of the sequence.